# variable file names in actionscript 3 using the date

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

Ok another question, How would i go about setting the **current date/time** when the user hits a submit button, into a **file name** for an **output string**.

i know how to set a standard static file name ie. `files/receipt.txt` and also researched  how to format standard output of the time and date using `<s:DateTimeFormatter id="dateTimeFormatter" dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short" locale="en-AU" />` that changes **Tue Jun 11 15:48:14 GMT+1000 2013** into this **11/06/2013 3:50 PM**

1. now i need to know how to remove the spaces for a file name
   and
2. how to set a variable file name ( like "files/`todaysDate`.txt" )

And thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date straight from the DateFormatter. For example, getting current Date & time to String:

```
//..
var todaysDate:String = getCurrentDate();
//..

private function getCurrentDate():String{
        var CurrentDateTime:Date = new Date();
        var CurrentDF:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
        CurrentDF.formatString = "MM/DD/YY LL:NN:SS A"
        var DateTimeString:String = CurrentDF.format(CurrentDateTime);
        return DateTimeString;

    }
```

So in your case you could use this as formatString:

```
 CurrentDF.formatString = "MM_DD_YY_LL_NN_SS_A"
```

so your string would look like 12_06_2013_12_56_AM.

Comment: thanks i will try that, the assignment has been handed in but i'd still like to get that working so future reference

Answer (score 0):

Set the `formatString` property on the `DateFormatter`. Here's the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html#formatString).

Comment: thanks that will definitely help with removing the space in the format. Now i just need to find out how to set a non-static file name now

Comment: Save the date to string and just use: var todaysDate:String; .. "files/"+todaysDate+".txt";

Comment: @Pete i tried that exact syntax, but not sure if i saved the data to a string, so 'i'll give that i try

Comment: @PeteTNT `var todaysDate:String;` that won't work will it doesn't it need to be 
`var todaysDate:Date=new Date().toString();` or something like that

(new to coding - student)